# Selecting values for each distinct ID based on the latest date

Tags: sql, mysql

I have the following table :

| ID | Height | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 168 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 173 | 2023-10-13 |
| 1 | 190 | 2022-04-01 |
| 2 | 157 | 2023-11-13 |

And I would like a query to select the height for each ID based on the latest date (not necessary in that order) :

| ID | Height | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 168 | 2022-12-01 |
| 2 | 157 | 2023-11-13 |

What would be the most efficient way to do this?